# How do I less a filename rather than an inode number?

Tags: logs, solaris, tail, less

I have a piece of software that rotates its log files when it restarts. However, during development, I am restarting it a lot, so I would like to monitor the latest log file at any time.

If I start `less` normally with `less program.log` and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to tail, when the log file is rotated, I carry on monitoring the old log file. I assume this is because the inode number stays the same and `less` has an open file handle to that inode.

Is it possible to monitor the latest activity on whatever log file is currently called `program.log`?

Specifically, I am working on Sun OS, so a solution that works there would be ideal.

Comment: maybe `tail -F program.log | less` will work

Comment: `tail -f program.log`  have you tried this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `less --follow-name` if your version of `less` supports it.
That option was introduced in version 416.

Then do a normal follow command <kbd>Shift+F</kbd> within `less`.

Comment: Excellent reply. Both Solaris 10 and Solaris 11 use less version 436 so this option is indeed available.

Answer (score 6):

The `less` option `--follow-name` is only part of the solution;
To replace `tail -F`, another argument is needed:

```
less --follow-name +F file.log
```

The option alone like `less --follow-name file.log` does not actually start following the file updates. You need to enter the follow mode be pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.
(Exit the mode to navigate by <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.)

Instead of following the file, `--follow-name` **modifies the behaviour** of less.
It makes the command key <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> inside of `less` follow based on the file name, not the file descriptor.

Also, there is no normal option to start `less` in follow mode.
But you can use the command line to give **keystrokes to execute** after startup, by prefixing them with `+`.
Combining the modifier option with `+F`, `less` will actually start in the (modified) follow mode.

Use `+F` alone for the equivalent of plain `tail -f`:

```
less +F file.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer in this U&L Q&A titled: [How to do a `tail -f` of log rotated files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22698/how-to-do-a-tail-f-of-log-rotated-files).

#### Using `tail`:

*(if installing GNU tail on your system is an option)*

```
tail -F program.log
```

From the [tail man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail):

```
   -f,      --follow[={name|descriptor}]
            output appended data as the file grows; -f, 
            --follow, and --follow=descriptor are equivalent

   -F       same as --follow=name --retry

   --retry  keep  trying  to  open  a  file even when it is or becomes
            inaccessible; useful when following by name, i.e., with
            --follow=name
```

The key is the `--retry` switch. This tells the `tail` command to keep retrying to follow a file by name. The `-F` switch does both a `-f` and a `--retry`.

#### Using `less`

As @StephaneChazela pointed out in the comments the following will not work.

```
tail -F program.log | less
```

The only other option you have is to use less directly assuming it supports the `--follow-name` switch and `less` the file directly, forgoing using `tail` completely.

```
less --follow-name program.log
```

Comment: I strongly dislike Sun OS sometimes...

Comment: I agree, I worked for years, it drives you nuts that the tooling is like 10 years old for some of the apps. Makes no sense. This site was invaluable for keeping your sanity on Solaris: http://www.sunfreeware.com/introduction.html

Comment: if you want more sanity, check out pkgsrc.org :)

Comment: That won't work nicely. Because `less` will hang if you do "G" pr "F". Which you can interrupt by doing "Ctrl-C", but then it kills tail. You can then immune tail to Ctrl-C, but it's still not very usable.

Comment: With regards to GNU tail:  Check out [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools/) for information about what tools should be available on any Solaris host. (Actually GNU tail is there by default in Solaris 11). Solaris sysadmins often make it harder for their users because they leave the install at the very bare-bone install while GNU tools for Solaris are actually these days available directly from Oracle or in some cases part of default install. No reason not to make it part of your install. No reason to go to 'unofficial' repos. See link.