# cygwin, tail -F and rapidly filling/rotatinglogs

Tags: tail, cygwin

I'm using cygwin tail to follow busy java web application logs, on a windows server, generating roughly 16Gb worth of logs a day.  I"m constrained to 10MB log sizes, so the files roll very often.

The command line I'm using is :

```
/usr/bin/tail -n 1000 -F //applicationserver/logs/logs.log
```

It survives 2-4 rolls of the file, about 4-6 minutes, but eventually, usually reports:

"File truncated" and then echos the name of the file every second.  the file is busily filling and rotating. Am I exceeding the capability of tail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to tailf achieved the results that I was looking for.  No combination of tail switches worked to keep it running longer than a few log roll-overs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the `-n 1000`?  Won't that very quickly scroll off screen?

This is similar to [How to do a `tail -f` of log rotated files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22698/how-to-do-a-tail-f-of-log-rotated-files), but notice you're already using `-F`, which includes `--retry`.

Perhaps try `--sleep-interval=1` to give tail less of a chance to miss the truncation?  There doesn't appear to be a noticeable difference in my (admittedly) limited testing.

Comment: -n 1000 does scroll off the screen, but that's ok, at the rate logs get filled, that's about a minute of logs, and if the server is in a stopped state, it's enough to scroll through to troubleshoot, quickly.  I tried --sleep-interval=1, but that's really the default behavior, anyway.  also added --max-unchanged-stats=1, tried both --follow types.  started looking at the source to tail.