# Trigger an action when an URL has been visited

Tags: grep, cron, apache-httpd, logs, email

Let's say I send an email, containing a link to my website, to someone that I really hope he'll visit it (fingers-crossed style):

```
http://www.example.com/?utm_source=email392
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/somefile.pdf?utm_source=email392
```

**How to make Linux trigger an action (such as sending an automated email to myself) when this URL is visited, by regularly examining `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log`?**

I can't do it at PHP level because I need to do it for various sources/websites (some of them use PHP, some don't and are just link to files to be downloaded, etc.; even for the websites using PHP, I don't want to modify every `index.php` to do it from there, that's why I prefer an Apache log parsing method)

Comment: Notice that the URL might be visited by something else (e.g. Google bots)

Comment: Yes @BasileStarynkevitch, I checked my logs and bots do visit my website, that's right, but they never do with the precise pattern `/?utm_source=onlycommunicated_tooneperson_viaemail`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Live log monitoring using bash process substitution:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='$\n' read -r line;
do
    # action here, log line in $line

done < <(tail -n 0 -f /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log | \
         grep '/somefile.pdf?utm_source=email392')
```

[*Process substitution*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) feeds the read loop with the output from the pipeline inside `<(...)`. The log line itself is assigned to variable `$line`.

Logs are watched using [`tail -f`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tail), which outputs lines as they are written to the logs. If your log files are moved periodically by *logrotate*, add `--follow=name` and `--retry` options to watch the file path instead of just the file descriptor.

Output from *tail* is piped to [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), which filters the relevant lines matching your URLs.

Comment: Much better than my own answer. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference: `tail -n 0` makes a clean / empty start of tail (no default 10 lines).

Comment: @sebasth can you post an example with `follow=name` and `retry`? Should I replace `name` by the actual path?

Comment: @sebasth can I use `tail -F -n 0` instead of `-f --follow=name --retry`? This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22698/how-to-do-a-tail-f-of-log-rotated-files) seems to suggest it.

Comment: `tail -n 0 -f --follow=name --retry /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log | ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can take a one liner like this:

`grep -q "utm_source=email392" /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log && grep -q "utm_source=email392" /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log | mail -S "Accessed!" foo@bar.com`

and run it periodically via `cron`.

Explaining it in more detail: the first `grep` is used only to check if further action is needed (adding `-q` makes it quiet, hiding any matches it might find).  `&&` means that the rest of the line will only run if the first `grep` finds a match (i.e. returns 0). If that is the case, the matching line(s) obtained by the second `grep` are piped into `mail` to be sent to `foo@bar.com`, on an email with the subject specified by the `-s` argument ("*Acessed!*").

The same logic (`grep -q ... && ...`) can be used to perform any other actions.  You can run whatever you want after `&&`, e.g. a shell script for more complex stuff.

Note that if you run this at a higher frequency than the log's rotation -- e.g. checking hourly but rotating the logs daily -- the action might be triggered multiple times, since `grep` will keep finding the same line(s) over and over again until the log rotates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is a problem indeed: "if you run this at a higher frequency than the log's rotation -- e.g. checking hourly but rotating the logs daily -- the action might be triggered multiple times", because I only rotate logs weekly.

Answer (score 1):

While I wrote my solution I've found that the first answer is similar to mine. I would recommend to avoid crontab too in this case. I'll post my code .

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"
pattern="$2"

tail -f -n0 $file | {
   while IFS= read -r line
   do
      if [ ! -z $(echo $line | grep "$pattern") ] ; then
         echo "visited $pattern" | mail user@example.com
      fi
   done
}
```

In addition you can run it on the backround with the `&` operator:

`./checklog.sh /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log "somefile.pdf?utm_source=email392" &`

or start it as a 'daemon' when the system boots up

Comment: NIce! Will this run forever? (I would like this: run forever, until I kill it). Also will it reopen the file automatically when the logs rotate?

Comment: It will run until you kill it or the system goes down (in almost any case) :-)
As mentioned in the first answer by sebasth, you can use the `--follow` and `--retry` options when the log rotates. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Why did you put `while IFS=(nothinghere) read -r line`?

Comment: The value of the `IFS` (internal field separator) variable holds the character(s) used to split the string read. Therefore `read` will assign the whole line to `line` when `IFS` is empty.

Comment: Thanks again. Now a [linked issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392457/too-many-emails-sent-when-sending-emails-when-specific-url-has-been-visited-in-a) just in case you have an idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try fail2ban with filter apache-badbots.conf, (replace the regex with your url)
and as action sendmail.conf

`[mycustombot]
enable = true 
filter = apache-badbots ##your "custom" script
action = sendmail[name=MyBadBot,dest=youremail@be.happy]
logpath = /your/access/logs/*/path`

Answer (score 0):

Posting what I'm finally using, for future reference (ok I know one liners are sometimes bad, but...):

```
tail -F -n0 /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log | grep --line-buffered "?src=_" | { while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line" | mail test@example.com; done } &
```

Notes:

- I have to use `grep --line-buffered` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7162898/1422096).
- `tail -F` seems to replace `--follow=name --retry`, as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22698/how-to-do-a-tail-f-of-log-rotated-files).

(Of course credit goes to sebasth and Wax.)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using rsyslog and the ommail module

http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/ommail.html

something like:

```
module(load="ommail")

if $msg contains "/somefile.pdf?utm_source=email392" then {
   action(type="ommail" server="..." port=".."
       mailfrom="...."
       mailto="..."
       subject.text="Page Viewed!")
}
```

this will work if apache is configured to log using syslog