# Too many emails sent when sending emails when specific URL has been visited in Apache Logs

Tags: grep, logs, email, tail

In this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391813/trigger-an-action-when-an-url-has-been-visited/392441#392441), a solution was found to automatically send an email each time a specific URL is visited (such as `?src=foo`), as seen in the Apache logs:

```
tail -F -n0 /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log | grep --line-buffered "?src=foo" | \
        { while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line" | mail test@example.com; done } &
```

But the problem is that any other ressource being loaded on this page (images, favicon, etc.) have this pattern `?src=foo` in the **referrer** column too:

```
www.example.fr:80 111.111.111.111 - - [12/Sep/2017:17:30:32 +0200] "GET /images/P26372.jpg 
  HTTP/1.1" 200 86276 "http://example.fr/?src=foo" "Mozilla/5.0"
```

Then I'm receiving 15 emails in a row with this method.

**How to limit to do a "digest" of this?**

I thought about limiting the search for the pattern inside `"GET ... HTTP"` so it would exclude a result in the referred column, but how to do this?

Or, alternatively, would it be possible to send only an email twice per day with all the results of `grep`? (no email sent is nothing is found)

Comment: Sending an email when an URL is visited is a really bad idea (what would happen if I `curl`ed your URL in a tight loop?).  Just use a log analyzer for Apache.

Comment: @SatōKatsura I use it *only in a very narrow specific case* for being informed quickly that someone visited the link I sent via email. Example: you send `example.com/superimportantfile.pdf?src=JH2KS79x0v9t8` (with an impossible-to-guess pattern) to someone and you want to be informed by email.

Comment: Again: would you mind if I `curl`ed that page in a tight loop?

Comment: @SatōKatsura for this you need to have access to the pattern `JH2KS79x0v9t8` to trigger an email. And this pattern is only communicated to one person that I know.

Comment: Security by obscurity.  What could possibly go wrong with that. :)

Comment: I learned something cool thanks to your comment @SatōKatsura, thanks! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: Can you provide some example lines which should and should not trigger the email sending? Do not forget, you can always add new layers of `grep` pattern searches through pipes :-)

You said in the question, alternatively, would it be possible to send an email twice a day but in the comments that this is for to be quickly informed. If you get emails in predetermined intervals, it will not be as quick as I think you want it to be.
But I would redirect the output of the command/script to a file and check it periodically if it's empty. If you want it I'll write my idea more briefly.

Answer (score 0):

There are log scanners that offer rate limits on the noise they generate; I'd use [`sec.pl`](https://simple-evcorr.github.io) and then configuration along the lines of

```
type=SingleWithThreshold
ptype=SubStr
pattern=?src=foo
desc=specific-url-thing
action=pipe 'that url thing happened' /usr/bin/mail -s url-thing test@example.com
window=86400
thresh=1
```

For a daemon instance watching the log in question. This should trigger right away, and then shut up for a day; there are other options to aggregate the hits and so forth, see the manual for details.