# tail -f, but when the file is deleted and re-created (not appended)

Tags: tail

I'm trying to watch for any new output of a log file. Another script (not under my control) is deleting the file then creating a new one with the same name. Using `tail -f` doesn't work because the file is being deleted.

Comment: If Linux, use `-F` instead of `-f`.  It's a GNU extension that will follow the file by name and keep retrying.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22698/how-to-do-a-tail-f-of-log-rotated-files

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If your `tail` supports it, use [`tail -F`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html#tail-invocation), it works nicely with disappearing and re-appearing files. Just make sure you start `tail` from a directory which will stay in place.

`-F` is short-hand for `--follow=name --retry`: `tail` will follow files by name rather than file descriptor, and will retry when files are inaccessible (*e.g.* because they’ve been deleted).

(A number of bugs relating to `--follow=name` with `--retry` were fixed in coreutils 8.26, so you may run into issues with earlier versions; *e.g.* retrying when the directory containing the tailed file is deleted appears to only work in all cases with version 8.26 or later.)

Comment: As a side note, `less` too has a `--follow-name` option that works in the same way.

Comment: but if files containing that file is removed as well, `tail -F ` prints, that it reverts to polling, but it will never print anything from that time on.

Comment: @Martin what version of coreutils are you using? I’ve just checked with 8.30, and `tail -F` works fine, even if the directory containing the tailed file(s) is deleted (and recreated). As I mention in the answer, a number of issues were fixed in 8.26.

Comment: my is version 8.31

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at your tail man command, some have:

```
--follow=name
```

which instructs `tail` to watch for the name, and not the descriptor as it does by default.
With such an option, if the file is deleted and recreated, `tail` will see it.
As written in the manual:

> With --follow (-f), tail defaults to following the file descriptor, which means that even if a tail'ed file is renamed, tail will continue to track its end.  This default behavior is not desirable when you really want to track the actual name of the file, not the file  descriptor  (e.g.,  log  rotation).   Use  --follow=name in that case.  That causes tail to track the named file in a way that accommodates renaming, removal and creation.

Comment: To survive file deletion in all cases, you need `--retry`, which is what `-F` does.