# How to tail continuously a log file that is being deleted and recreated?

Tags: bash, grep, logs, tail, control-flow

I need to extract information from a log file that is deleted and recreated every time a program runs. After detecting that the file exists (again), I would like to `tail` it for a certain regexp.

The regexp will be matched a few times, but the result is always the same and I want to print it just once and after that go back to monitoring when the file is re-created.

I looked at ways of detecting file creation. One way would be via [`inotifywait`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70132359/how-to-use-inotifywait-to-wait-till-a-file-is-created-and-is-written-content-wit), but that requires installing a separate package.

Perhaps a simpler way is to take advantage that tail prints to `stderr` when a file that is being tailed is deleted and created:

```
tail: '/path/to/debug.log' has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
tail: '/path/to/debug.log' has appeared;  following new file
```

So I applied [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/900134) which is working:

```
debug_file="/path/to/debug.log"

while true; do
    # Monitor the log file until the 'new file' message appears
    ( tail -F $debug_file 2>&1 & ) | grep -q "has appeared;  following new file"
    
    # After the new file message appears, switch to monitoring for the regexp
    tail -F "$debug_file" | while read -r line; do
        id=$(echo "$line" | sed -n 's/.* etc \([0-9]\+\),.*/\1/p')
        if [ -n "$id" ]; then
            echo "ID: $id"
            break  # Exit the inner loop after the first match
        fi
    done
done
```

But I don't like that this solution starts 2 different `tail` processes. Is there a way to achieve the same result, but using just 1 `tail` process?

And then switch 'modes', start by looking for file creation, then look for the regexp and once that is found go back to 'standby' mode waiting for the log file to be deleted and created again.

Is inotifywait a more elegant solution? Ideally I would like a solution I could port easily to Windows CMD.

Comment: I think this may be similar to the issue posed by this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410471/tail-f-but-when-the-file-is-deleted-and-re-created-not-appended#:~:text=Just%20make%20sure,they%E2%80%99ve%20been%20deleted%29.

Comment: Is there any point in using `tail` here? You're not watching the output, you seem to only care about a single value, so why bring `tail` in at all? Why not just `grep` the file for your pattern?

Comment: I want to monitor the file over several consecutive cycles of delete file -> create new file -> populate with data, so using tail is nice because it keeps the process active and adds a line to the console every time the cycle repeats. The initial problem was that the script would terminate as soon as sed found a match and the behaviour I'm looking for is to print the match and go back to listening mode.

Comment: But why would `tail` be needed over just running `grep`? Why is it a good thing to keep the process active?

Comment: Suppose you open the clock app in your computer. Every time you open the app, a log file is deleted, created new and populated with the time. Now imagine you open and close the clock app repeatedly. At the same time, you want a terminal window open printing the time that is saved in the log file. It makes sense to me to use tail, but perhaps there is a way to use grep that also continuously monitors the log file for changes and prints the time every time the clock app is opened?

Comment: Can't you just use `tail -F FILE`? Works even for files which not even exists (yet).

Comment: have you check `--follow=name` option ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't need the outer loop. piping tail output into read might allow you to operate in a kind of state machine, where you are in two states. a normal tail state, and a new file state, where you wait for the next match to print your "ID: " line.

I'd imagine you'd want to try redirecting stderr into stdout while reading, though. added some pseudo-code to your sample.

```
debug_file="/path/to/debug.log"

# After the new file message appears, switch to monitoring for the regexp
# state="new_file"
tail -F "$debug_file" 2>&1 | while read -r line; do
    # if state = "new_file"
        id=$(echo "$line" | sed -n 's/.* etc \([0-9]\+\),.*/\1/p')
        if [ -n "$id" ]; then
            echo "ID: $id"
            # state = "id_printed"
        fi
    # else
        # if line contains "has appeared;  following new file"
            # state = new_file
        # echo "$line"
    # fi
done
```

Edit. The above solution would be necessary if there can be multiple matches of the regular expression in the file, and you only want to match the first one. Otherwise, you could probably create a somewhat complicated one-liner using `tail -F | grep | sed` (could also potentially use awk instead of sed). You may even be able to get away with just tail and grep, using the -o option, depending on your requirements.

e.g. try: `tail -F /path/to/debug.log | grep -E '.* etc ([0-9]+),.*'`, and then see how you'd want to transform it from there.

Comment: So your suggestion is essentially to use flags?

Comment: if by flags, you mean ways we pass options to commands, no. if by flags, you mean using a variable to track state based on contents of a line, then yes.

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Using [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
(open-tail "/path/to/debug.log")  ;; returns a stream that follows rotating log
```

You just read input from this stream, e.g. using something like:

```
(with-stream (s (open-tail "/path/to/debug.log"))
  (whilet ((ln (get-line s)))
    (if-match `@nil etc @id,@nil` ln
      (put-line `ID: @id`))))
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to continuously tail a file across recreations and only output unique lines is:

```
tail -F "$debug_file" 2>/dev/null | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

and if you only want to consider parts of lines that the regexp in your sed command `sed -n 's/.* etc \([0-9]\+\),.*/\1/p'` would produce you could do this (untested) using GNU awk for the 3rg arg to `match()`

```
tail -F "$debug_file" 2>/dev/null |
awk 'match($0,/.* etc ([0-9]+),/,a) && !seen[a[1]]++ { print "ID: " a[1] }'
```

or this using any awk:

```
tail -F "$debug_file" 2>/dev/null |
awk '/.* etc [0-9]+,/ && sub(/.* etc /,"") && sub(/,.*/,"") && !seen[$0]++ { print "ID: " $0 }'
```

and if you wanted to discard any "IDs" seen in the previous iteration of the input then you could do:

```
tail -F "$debug_file" 2>&1 |
awk '
    /^tail: \047.*\047 has appeared;  following new file$/ { delete seen }
    ... code from above ...
'
```

assuming the file you're tailing can't itself contain lines matching that `^tail:.*` regexp.

There's a good chance that this:

```
awk '/.* etc [0-9]+,/ && sub(/.* etc /,"") && sub(/,.*/,"") && !seen[$0]++ { print "ID: " $0 }'
```

could actually be written as something more concise like:

```
awk '$(X-1) == "etc" && !seen[$X]++ { print "ID: " $X+0 }'
```

where `X` is whatever the space-separated field number is that contains the ID number but without seeing an example of your log file, I don't know if that'd work or not and, if it did, what value `X` would have, nor exactly what the condition would look like.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions with awk, I'll take a look carefully. Although the main point of the question was more about the structure of the code in a case where the log file is deleted between data retrieval events. I think I found an acceptable solution and I'll update the question once I look at replacing sedwith awk.

Comment: To be clear, you wouldn't be replacing sed with awk you'd be replacing the shell loop (which just happens to include a call to sed) with awk. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).